# Airflow 1.10.15 - Hooks that run DB functions must inherit from DBApiHook

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I'm running the Bridge 1.10.15 airflow version so we can migrate to Airflow 2, and I ran `airflow upgrade_check` and I'm seeing this FAILED:

> Hooks that run DB functions must inherit from DBApiHook

I have this custom hook in plugins:

```
class _FacebookBaseOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.local_folder = 'FBK'
        self.fbhook = None


class FacebookLoadPageInfoAndTokensOperator(_FacebookBaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 operation='page_info_and_tokens',
                 *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.operation = operation



 def execute(self, context):
        self.fbhook = FacebookHook()
        ds = context['execution_date'].date()
        data = self.fbhook.load_page_info_and_tokens()
        s3_ingest = CsvS3(
            operation=self.operation,
            concurrency='all',
            header=page_infos_pages_header,
            array_data=data
        )
        s3_ingest.run()
```

This is what I've found in the documentation that I think pertains to this error: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a17db7883044889b2b2001cefc41a8960359a23f/UPDATING.md#remove-sql-support-in-basehook

Would I just change the import:

```
from airflow.hooks.dbapi_hook import DbApiHook
```

and change the class inheritance to:

```
class _FacebookBaseOperator(DbApiHook):
```

Comment: Can you please share the whole plugin code?

Comment: @Elad I've updated for the whole code that's using the BaseHook

Comment: Do you call somewhere in your code to one of the 3 functions that were moved to dbapihook? Your code doesnt show it but you are calling to functions that you did not show thier code...

Comment: @Elad thanks for responding again, sorry I've updated! I don't call anywhere to the 3 functions that were moved to the dbapihook, which is why I'm confused. Is there a way I can get more information like where exactly the error is coming from other then 'Hooks that run DB functions must inherit from DBApiHook'

Comment: What is Csv3 class?

Comment: @Elad 

CSV3 class is:

 class CsvS3:
    def __init__(self,
                 ds,
                 header=None,
                 concurrency='all'):
        self.concurrency = concurrency
        self.ds = ds
        self._header = header

    def csv_params(self):
        """
        kwargs passed to csv.writer
        """
        return dict(delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

is it possible that in the def execute function in my original post that s3_ingest.run()  is what Dbapihook was referring to with run() in the documentation I posted earlier?